# How to prevent decoding of encoded forward slashes in Windows Live mail?

Tags: c#, asp.net, base64, urlencode, outlook.com

I've got aform with a continue link that is send by email. In this link I've added some sensitive encrypted data that is encoded by `Base64`. The value contains a slash which is encoded into `%2F` (with a `Server.UrlEncode`). When I send the link to a Windows Live address I see that Outlook.com decodes the `%2F` back into a forward slash. How can I prevent this?

I'm sending:
`<a href="http://www.tempuri.com/key=RVQ%2FcGhvbmVfaG9tZSE%3D">Continue</a>`

But I'm seeing:
`<a href="http://www.tempuri.com/key=RVQ/cGhvbmVfaG9tZSE=%3D">Continue</a>`

It can be reproduced by sending the link `http://www.tempuri.com/key=RVQ%2FcGhvbmVfaG9tZSE%3D` from *any mail client* to the Windows Live address.

Comment: Please provide a snapshot of your code so that we may help !

Comment: Just to be clear, Base64 encoding doesn't provide any sort of encryption whatsoever, and anybody can decode it.  Use the MachineKey.Protect static method if you need to perform encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode the value twice.

So `RVQ/cGhvbmVfaG9tZSE=` is encoded as `RVQ%2FcGhvbmVfaG9tZSE%3D` --> this was your value.

Now encode this, and you get `RVQ%252FcGhvbmVfaG9tZSE%253D` --> the email client won't decode %252F to a slash so your problem is gone.

Just don't forget to decode the value twice ;-)

Comment: Would work, but the mail goes out to many types of clients :(